# Postman sign query using dynamic tumestamp

Tags: dynamic, postman, sha256

I need to send a query using postman that will send using POST multiple variables. My problem is that one of the variables needs to be dynamically calculated as follows:

SHA256 (API public key + the date and hour the call is made (YYYYMMDDHHNN))

I could not find how to set up postman to automatically generate this parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script like this in the Pre-request Script, to generate the value:

```js
const moment = require('moment');
let time = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$timestamp}}'),
    formattedTimestamp = moment.unix(time).format('YYYYMMDDHHNN'),
    APIPublicKey = '12345ABCDE';

pm.variables.set('token', APIPublicKey + formattedTimestamp);
```

Replacing the `APIPublicKey` value with your key to generate the variable. This creates a variable that can be used at runtime and isn't stored anywhere. Using this variable would be as simple as adding `{{token}}` into the area of the request that is was required.

Using [CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) with those variable values:

```js
const moment = require('moment');

let time = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$timestamp}}'),
    formattedTimestamp = moment.unix(time).format('YYYYMMDDHHNN'),
    APIPublicKey = '12345ABCDE';

// Generate the hash using HMAC-SHA256 and encode to Base64
let hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(APIPublicKey, formattedTimestamp).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

pm.variables.set('token', hash);
```

Comment: But what about the SHA256 signature?

Comment: Isn't that the API Key + date and hour? That's what should be getting saved in the variable. I just mocked it out here to show you the dynamic date/hour part.

Comment: yes but the variable needs to be signed using SHA256

Comment: Updated to use cryptojs - I'd be lying if I said I knew a lot about this though :/